My splash screen doesn't appear when launching my Next.js PWA on ios
My splash screen doesn't appear when launching i'm launching my app.
I only see a white screen when launching the app.
I tried changing Next Metadata object like this and I rebuild the PWA app many time:
appleWebApp: {
    title: `Apple ${APP_DEFAULT_TITLE}`,
    capable: true,
    statusBarStyle: "black-translucent",
    startupImage: "/splash_screens/icon.png"
  }

Here the start of my manifest.json:
"id": "/",
  "name": "Instamint",
  "theme_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait"


I had this issue before, and I fixed it by changing the resolution of images. Could you provide me with the resolutions for your apple-touch-startup-image?

I found out fixing all warning in manifest.json (using chrome lighthouse) also fixed my issue of the splash screen not appearing. I kept the same image as before in my Next Metadata object.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
